# Correct syntax for reading from a nested array in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nested

Essentially I'm trying to grab in integer from an Array -> Dictionary -> Array -> Int. What I have produces no console errors and compiles fine, but always returns 0. I think my syntax is wrong but I'm not sure of the correct way to rewrite it.

```
convenience init(fromDict dict: [String: Any]) {
    let dfa = dict["forms"] as? Array<Dictionary<String,Array<Any>>>
    self.init(
        heart: dfa?[0]["abilities"]?[0] as? Int ?? 0
    )
}
```

`<array>
          <dict>
               <key>forms</key>
               <array>
                     <dict>
                          <key>abilities</key>
                          </array>
                                 <integer>65</integer>
                          </array>`

Comment: The first thing to do is see whether `dfa` itself is `nil`. Is it?

Comment: dfa is giving me the breakpoint error when I remove the `?`s. It shouldn't as I can see the variable in the data source

Comment: You can see the variable but maybe it does not have a `["forms"]` entry, and, if it does, maybe that entry's value is not a `Array<Dictionary<String,Array<Any>>>`. Do you see? You have not shown _us_ what `dict` consists of, though. You are keeping everything secret so no one can help you. That is why I am giving you instructions for thinking about the matter yourself.

Comment: Yes I used `let dfs = dict["forms"] as? Array<Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,Any>>>` To grab a value from a dictionary in `["forms"]`. There is an array in `["forms"]` that I cannot seem to extract this data from

Comment: If that is supposed to be a plist, or xml of any kind, it is totally malformed.

Comment: Xcode won't give me the option to copy/paste the source code. I just typed out the path to the integer

Comment: Xcode will show you a plist as source. You can then copy it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131989/discussion-between-user4938361-and-matt).

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks ok to me, although I would suggest making the inner array contain `Int` rather than `Any` if it will always contain ints. That way you can lose that final cast to Int type.

If either of your conditional casts fails then you'll get nil, and the nil coalescing operator will convert your nil into a 0. I suggest writing debug code that logs the object passed into your init method, and then casting one thing at a time and stepping through to see where it fails.

(As Matt says in his comment, if the first conditional cast fails, your `dfa` variable will be nil.)

Comment: Force unwrapping it gives me EXC BREAKPOINT. But why would it be turning nil when the variable is at the designated location?

Comment: `as?` is a conditional cast that returns an opional that ether contains the correct type, or nil if the cast fails. It sounds like something in your object graph does not match the type(s) you are expecting, so the cast is failing. (Do not force-unwrap.)

Comment: updates the post with the plist source if that helps. I can't find the source of this issue